# Okta OAuth 2.0 - Invalid access token from Spring Boot resource server

Tags: typescript, spring-boot, vue.js, okta-api

Recently I've tried to create a small app, based on the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBXmi-J4LQs).

At one point, the author of the video reaches a "401 (Unauthorized)" error upon accessing the REST API's URLs and fixes that by appending an **Authorization: Bearer 'generated token hash here'**.

However, I keep getting the same 401 error. If I check the request to the URL, I see that there is an "invalid_token" error with the description **"Invalid access token: < access token hash here >"**

My `okta.oauth2.issuer` in `application.properties` is in the format https://dev-XXXXXX.okta.com/oauth2/default

I have an Okta configuration class on the Spring Boot side that looks like this:

```
@Configuration 
     public class OktaOAuth2Configuration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
      {
          @Override
          protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
           http
               .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
               .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
         }
    }
```

On the Vue.js side, I add the access token in the following way:

```
const response = await axios.get('/goodBeers', {
                     headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${await this.$auth.getAccessToken()}`,
                    },
                });
```

Do I need to do some additional configuration of either Spring Boot or Vue.js?

**EDIT:** Here are my response headers and request headers --> [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdLFA.jpg)

**EDIT 2:** I realized that I've created a Web app in Okta instead of a SPA like in the video above. I corrected that but the error is the exact same one as before that.

**EDIT 3:** The problem is related to the `@EnableResourceServer` annotation in Spring Boot. I'm assuming I'm missing some kind of configuration.

**EDIT 4:** Whenever I go incognito and try to access the API, I get the same error but instead of "Invalid token: " I get "Invalid token: undefined" instead.

**EDIT 5:** I have changed the `issuer` to contain `oktapreview` instead of just `okta`, as is in the github repo for the example in the video. However, that just changes the error to an Okta login error that says "The requested feature is not enabled in this environment"

Comment: Make sure your computer's clock is synced to internet time. I've seen that cause this issue in the past.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, my computer's clock was indeed not synced to the current time zone's time. However, the problem persists - same error - "Invalid access token".

Comment: Can you try in an incognito window and see if that solves it. When I've seen this happen before, it's because the clientId is wrong, the clock is wrong, or you're using the default issuer (w/o `/oauth2/default`).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Which issuer should I be using then - isn't `/oauth2/default` the go-to issuer to use? I have updated my question with the details of the incognito window tests.